# Updating a rails partial with Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I currently have two divs, one that contains a search bar and one that contains a partial, as such:

```
<div class="search_div">
    <%= form_tag(barpage_outings_path, :method => :get, :id => 'bars_search_form', :remote => true ) do %>
        <div id="user_search" class="in-field">
            <%= text_field_tag('search', '', :id => 'search_field') %>
            <%= label_tag 'search_field', 'Search For Locations' %>
            <%= submit_tag "", :id => "search_button" %> 
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div id="bar_partial">
    <%= render(:partial => "bar_results") %>
</div>
```

It renders a partial just fine upon page load, but I'd like it to refresh the partials contents after each search submission.

I have the form bound to an AJAX call, like such:

```
$('#bars_search_form').bind('ajax:success', function(){

   $('#bar_partial').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'bar_results')).html_safe %>");

});
```

The problem is, instead of refreshing the partial, it just outputs my escape javascript command as plain text. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong (or even if I'm going about this in the completely wrong way?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try this way:

https://gist.github.com/2230354

Comment: You may have just saved my life. I'll report back in a bit!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. The form doesn't even submit. However, it looks like there are some useful pieces here I should be able to play around with.

Comment: So, I figured it out. Short answer: I'm dumb. Long answer: the file I was calling the escape_javascript command from was a plain old .js file, not a js.erb, so naturally it didn't know what to do with the command. I've accepted your answer, since (once I got past my own idiocy) it helped tremendously in solving the actual problem I was working on.

Answer (score 0):

What about to make a new action that render your results? I think this is a better solution to your problem.

Comment: I thought about that, too, but I wasn't sure how to get a new action to fire upon submitting search results without binding it to an AJAX call, and -- as you can see -- my JS solution isn't working too great.

Comment: You can call a javascript function that execute to ajax request with onSubmit in your form or bind it in your submit button.